# Get Junit test results to appear in TeamCity's Testing tab

Tags: maven, testing, junit, teamcity, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a TeamCity job that would build my project by:

1. Running `docker build`
2. Within Dockerfile, will execute `RUN ["mvn", "clean", "package"]`

I am using Maven, JUnit5, and SureFire. I want to pipe my unit test results into TeamCity's Testing tab but am unsure how I can do this with my current setup.

In my Jest set-up, I am using `jest-teamcity-reporter`. The only JUnit plugin I have found is `Serenity TeamCity StepListener` but I cannot get the test results displayed on TeamCity's Testing tab.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity is supporting JUnit tests out of the box, when build step's runner type is Maven.

I see two options here:

- You building with docker, so select an option to run build step in docker container under the "Docker settings" of the Maven step. Then, JUnit test reports will be picked automatically. See TeamCity [Docker Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2021.1/docker-wrapper.html#Docker+Settings) documentation.
- On the other hand, you can run the build as usual and import test reports using [XML report processing](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/xml-report-processing.html) TeamCity feature.
  Don't forget to mount a container volume where the test reports are created into the TeamCity checkout directory. In order to do that, pass the following mount option to the `docker run ...` command:

  `--mount "type=bind,source=$PWD/surefire-reports,destination=/your/container/dir/surefire-reports`

You can use either of these two options which is looks convenient to you.